# MS Access Distinct Records in Recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, I once again seem to have an issue with MS Access being finicky, although it seems to also be an issue when trying similar queries in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

I have a collection of tables, loosely defined as follows:

1. table widget_mfg { id (int), name (nvarchar) }
2. table widget { id (int), name (nvarchar), mfg_id (int) }
3. table widget_component { id (int), name (nvarchar), widget_id (int), component_id }
4. table component { id (int), name (nvarchar), ... } -- There are ~25 columns in this table

What I'd like to do is query the database and get a list of all components that a specific manufacturer uses. I've tried some of these queries:

```
SELECT c.*, wc.widget_id, w.mfg_id
FROM ((widget_component wc INNER JOIN widget w ON wc.widget_id = w.id)
INNER JOIN widget_manufacturer wm on w.mfg_id = wm.id)
INNER JOIN component c on c.id = wc.component_id
WHERE wm.id = 1
```

The previous example displays duplicates of any part that is contained in multiple widget_component lists for different widgets.

I've also tried doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name, wc.widget_id, w.mfg_id
FROM component c, widget_component wc, widget w, widget_manufacturer wm
WHERE wm.id=w.mfg_id AND wm.id = 1
```

This doesn't display anything at all. I was reading about sub-queries, but I do not understand how they work or how they would apply to my current application.

Any assistance in this would be beneficial.

As an aside, I am not very good with either MS Access or SQL in general. I know the basics, but not a lot beyond that.

Edit:

I just tried this code, and it works to get all the component.id's while limiting them to a single entry each. How do I go about using the results of this to get a list of all the rest of the component data (component.*) where the id's from the first part are used to select this data?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.part_no
FROM component c, widget w, widget_component wc, widget_manufacturer wm
WHERE(((c.id=wc.component_id AND wc.widget_id=w.id AND w.mfg_id=wm.id AND wm.id=1)))
```

(P.S. this is probably not the best way to do this, but I am still learning SQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is query the database and get a list of all
>   components that a specific manufacturer uses

There are several ways to do this. IN is probably the easiest to write

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   component c 
WHERE  c.id IN (SELECT c.component_id 
                FROM   widget w 
                       INNER JOIN widget_component c 
                         ON w.id = c.widget_id 
                WHERE  w.mfg_id = 123)
```

The IN sub query finds all the component ids that a specific manufacturer uses. The outer query then selects any component.id that is that result. It doesn't matter if its in there once or 1000 times it will only get the component record once.

The other ways of doing this are using an EXISTS sub query or using a join to the query (but then you do need to de-dup it)

Comment: I tested this, and it does work. I don't understand why or how it works, however. I would like to understand why.

Comment: I think I see what is going on. The subquery is just generating a recordset of widget_component.component_id in which the main query is basically testing component.id=widget_component.component_id. Kind of like a foreach loop in php, but with the recordset. Does this sound about right?

Comment: Just an FYI: there is a slight issue when running this SQL code in MS Access. For some reason on SSMS it returns the correct resultset, but in Access it returns a resultset as if the WHERE clause is non-existant. I don't know why this happens. I also had to write some weird queries to get it to give me the same result in Access that it does in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your component -to- widget relationship is one-to-many.  Hence the duplicates.  (i.e., the same component is used by more than one widget).

Your Select is almost OK --

```
SELECT c.*, wc.widget_id, w.mfg_id
```

but the `wc.widget_id` is causing the duplicates (per the assumption above).

So remove `wc.widget_id` from the `SELECT`, or else aggregate it (`min`, `max`, `count`, etc.).  Removing is easier.  If you agregate, remember to add a `group by` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, w.mfg_id
```

Also -- FWIW, it's generally a better practice to use field names, instead of the *

Comment: I test this, and it does work. I think I understand why the wc.widget_id was causing duplicates. I would like to know why it is better practice to use field names instead of .*, especially if the table has a largish amount of fields available.

Comment: The asterisk issue has to do with the way SQL-Server executes a query -- just generally, an asterisk precludes performance benefits from indexing, by causing a full table scan; and by causing you to pass more data (fields you don't need, etc.) over the connection, etc.  Other database servers solve some of the performance issues better than SQL-Server does, but it seems that there's always a hit against your performance on some level.  Also, you'll do a better job developing -- thinking your query through, what you intend to have it do, etc. -- if you list out the fields.  FWIW.